# Home directory for bundled version of JDK in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea

I have JDK 7 installed on my machine, but I want to compile against JDK 8 using IntelliJ IDEA.

In the window that opens when choosing `Help > About`, there is the following line:

> JRE: 1.8.0_51-b16 x86

Well, IDE is running on Java 8. In fact, [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827547-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) it states:

> JDK is bundled with all the product installers and it's recommended that you will use the provided JDK version unless there are any specific issues.

That's great! I should be able to use the bundled version with my projects too.
But where is that JDK located?

When selecting the home directory for a new project, the default path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.1\jre`, but it doesn't work.

> The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK

After exploring a bit, I found `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.1\jre\jre\bin`. It contains many files, even some called `java.exe` and `javaw.exe`, but it doesn't work.

So where is the home directory for the bundled version of the JDK installed with IDEA?

Comment: It a **JRE** not a **JDK**!

Comment: @BoristheSpider The linked post also states: `32-bit JDK is located in IDE_HOME\jre directory and is used by the 32-bit product executable.`. While running the 64-bit executable, it appears to be using JDK 7. Is there a 32-bit version only of JDK 8 bundled with the installer, and not a 64-bit version too?

Comment: If it doesn't have a `javac`, you cannot develop with it :)

Comment: There is a bundled version of the JRE. Not the JDK. If you navigate to the folder, there is no `jdk/bin` folder containing `javac`. I suspect that the documentation you found has a typo. **You cannot use a JRE for development**.

Comment: At least on Mac they bundle the full JDK, not only the JRE (despite the folder in the application package is called "jre").

Comment: I just checked the Windows version of IntelliJ, and there they indeed only ship the JRE, not the JDK. So you have to install it manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know, where the bundled JDK is, try this:
[Ctrl+Shift+A] within IDEA and type "JDK" and select "Switch IDE Boot JDK"
You should see the bundled directory and you can switch to an other JDK path.
Please be aware that Java 8 is required to run IntelliJ IDEA starting from version 2016 on all the supported platforms.

EDIT:
Starting with version 2019.1:
[Ctrl+Shift+A] within IDEA and type and select "Choose Runtime..." (requires the 'Choose Runtime' Plugin)

[Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)